# Scala: Dynamic selection criteria as a method argument

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, anonymous-types

My intention is to create a function in Scala which accepts some kind of a dynamic query (similar to `case` expressions in pattern matching) and returns matching instances inside a `List`. Suppose that the list consists of instances of `case class Person` which has few properties with different types. The function should be able to accept a dynamic combination of values for some of the fields, and return matching `Person`s. I am specifically looking for a clean solution. One possible ways to use such a function would be to pass an object with an anonymous type as the query (the "pattern"):

```
def find(?): List<Person> = { ? }

val matches = find(new { val name = "Name"; val gender = Gender.MALE })
```

Ideally, I would like to develop a clean way of passing conditions, instead of concrete values, but it's not essential. Since I am learning Scala, I am not aware of all the techniques to implement such a thing. In C#, I used an anonymous type (similar to the second line of code above) and `dynamic` parameters to achieve something similar. What is a clean and elegant solution in Scala?

Comment: Anonymous predicates are not clear enough solution? `xs.find(person => person.name == "Name" && person.gender == Gender.MALE)`?

Comment: They are, if the criteria is static. Before runtime, it is not determined, for instance, whether name should be checked or not.

Comment: What you are describing looks similar to ScalaTest's matchers, where you could write something like `person should have ('name ("Name"), 'gender (Gender.MALE))`. While the matchers are used for assertions, you might be able to adjust the implementation for your purpose. Have a look at "Checking arbitrary properties with have": http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/matchers_quick_reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but let's try it this way:

First, we define `Person` as `case class Person(name: String, gender: Gender.Value)` where `Gender` is an already defined enum.

Then we create a `Query` case class which has the same fields, but as options which default to `None`, and a method for comparing the query to a person:

```
case class Query(name: Option[String] = None, 
                 gender: Option[Gender.Value] = None){

  def ===(person: Person) = check(person.name, name) && 
                            check(person.gender, gender)

  private def check[T](field: T, q: Option[T]) = field == q.getOrElse(field)
}
```

Unfortunately, in this solution `===` has to call `check` separately for each field. Let's leave it like that for now. Maybe it is sufficient (because, for example, the list of fields will not change).

Note that `check` returns `true` if the query's option is `None`, sot you don't have to pass all fields of the query:

```
val q = Query(name = Some("Ann")) // the gender is not important
q === Person("Ann", Gender.FEMALE) // returns true
```

And finally the `find` method:

```
def find(people: List[Person], query: Query) = people.filter(query === _)
```